# Stock inventory based in customer group

Tags: customer, inventory, customer-group

I need to set up 2 stock level, one per customer group (one for custom and one for wholesale) can someone point me to the right direction plz?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is looking for something similar I menaged this buying this exstension
https://www.wyomind.com/advanced-inventory-magento.html
It worked really good

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change stock level or qty attribute for different Customer Group. Qty has Global scope! You cannot change it from Admin Panel. But you can change Scope of Qty attribute from Global to Website, or, Store-view Level programmatically. If you want to manage two different stock inventory, you could use two different store-views in your magento.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i've just tried to switch from my storeviews and changed the qty field, but every time i change the quantity for a storeview it changes the quantity for all the other store views

Comment: When you are changing the stock qty, what's the scope? [GLOBAL] right? So, that's why it's not changing. You need to change scope of qty programmatically, not from Admin Panel. Custom Module or extension can help you. Like, http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_multi_location_inventory.html